# Tomcat web socket + AWS Bitnami

Tags: amazon-web-services, tomcat7, bitnami

I've tested a web socket project which uses tomcat7 on localhost and it works perfectly. I've deployed it into digital ocean server as well and it works perfectly. However when I tried to deploy it to AWS bitnami EC2 instance, it returned a "failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 500".

I would really appreciate it if a solution could be given or a step-by-step process to fix this. Currently there is no solution to be found on the web and I believe many people are facing this issue as well.

Comment: Please include the code that throws the exception, and the stack trace from the exception

Comment: Hi jrtapsell, the problem is there is no exception on Catalina.out . I'be searched a bit and all recommended to use AWS Elastic Load Balancer. Or do u have and idea how I could check the exceptions that you kindly mentioned?